# Google Geocoding API, moving from server-side to client-side, issues

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3

I have a store locator script running. The user enters their address, which is then geocoded, and the lat/lng are then passed to a MySQL query that selects locations within x-miles of the address. Today though I had my first issue with the following geocode server-side request:

```
$apiURL = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address,$city,$state,$zipcode&region=$country&key=$key");
$output= json_decode($apiURL);

$lat_lon->lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$lat_lon->lon = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

The issue is that I exceeded my 2500 requests limit. So, I read about client-side requests as a way to overcome this. I also read about caching the results, but I honestly believe that I will receive more than 2500 different address requests in a day. So, I want to go with client side.

After several hours my brain is wiped, as I'm completely new to Maps API. I have come up with the following javascript:

```
function GetLocation() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   geocoder.geocode( { 'address': <? echo $_POST['zipcode'] ?>}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    } 
});
};
```

My first question is, have I coded this correctly, to be a direct replacement for the server-side code, i.e will lat and lng return their equivalents from the server-side request ($lat_lon->lat and $lat_lon->lng)?

My second question is, how on earth do I pass the lat and lng variables to the MySQL query, which is in another file, coded in PHP? With the server-side coding, the geocoding function is in the same php file as the database query and so referencing $lat_lon-> is simple. However I've never done this type of coding before and my hours of trawling the web have resulted in nothing. I'm defeated.

Can anyone shed some light, please?

I don't know if it makes any difference but the query string is:

```
$query = "SELECT *,(((acos(sin(($lat*$pi/180)) * sin((lat*$pi/180)) + cos(($lat*$pi/180)) *  cos((lat*$pi/180)) * cos((($lon - lon)*$pi/180))))*180/$pi)*60*1.423) as distance FROM locations HAVING distance <= $radius AND $category_search AND (expiration_date >= NOW() || expiration_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00') ORDER BY distance ASC $results_limit";
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen this [article from the Google Maps Javascript API v3 documentation: Creating a Store Locator with PHP & MySQL](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3)?

Comment: i've never seen that before, many thanks for the link! it's been extremely useful.

Comment: i got a coding guy to fix it in the end. i am using autocomplete (google places) and so what he did was to grab the lat/lng from the autocomplete address and then append these as hidden fields in the form submit, so that:
'$lat_lon->lat = $_POST['lat'];
$lat_lon->lon = $_POST['lng'];'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I got a maps coder to work on this for me as it was way out of my league, and seeing what he did I am glad I didn't do it myself.

on my page with the search form, I have the autocomplete function which he changed to:

```
function fillInAddress() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

// HE ADDED THE NEXT 5 LINES TO THE FUNCTION
        var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
        var lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
        $(".storelocator_body form").find("input.geometry").remove();
        $(".storelocator_body form").append("<input type='hidden' class='geomtery' name='lat' value='" + lat + "'>");
        $(".storelocator_body form").append("<input type='hidden' class='geomtery' name='lng' value='" + lng + "'>");

        for (var component in componentForm) {
            document.getElementById(component).value = '';
            document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }
        if (place.address_components != undefined && place.address_components != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
            var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
            if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

then on the php file, where i had the original server-side geocode, he change it to:

```
if (isset($_POST['lat']) && isset($_POST['lng'])) {
      $lat_lon->lat = $_POST['lat'];
      $lat_lon->lon = $_POST['lng'];
  } else {

//THESE NEXT 4 LINES ARE THE ORIGINAL CODE, WHICH HE SUBSEQUENTLY ADDED TO
      $apiURL = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address,$city,$state,$zipcode&region=$country&key=$key");
      $output= json_decode($apiURL);
      $lat_lon->lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
      $lat_lon->lon = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
  }
```

Simple as that. Working now. Hope this helps anyone searching for a possible solution, like I was.